# How can I change Background Color of the Dropdown Contact Form Plugin

Tags: css, wordpress, forms

I trying to find out which Selectors its for the background Color of Dropdown Contactform.
I used many selector but nothing works.

Contact form:

[image: 1]

Comment: Providing text and code instead of images of code helps to get much faster recommendations from the community

Comment: for your code part provide text

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to select the option tags inside the select tag. See my example below.

I have an id of `#dropDown` on the select tag. Then, I use `#dropDown option` to change the color of the text inside the option tags in the dropdown.

So in the inspect tool, get the CSS attribute of that select element and change the color of the option children.

```css
html, body {
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            background-color: crimson;
        }

        #dropDown {
            background-color: transparent;
            color: white;
        }

        #dropDown option {
            color: black;
        }
```

```html
<form action="">
        <select name="" id="dropDown">
            <option value="">Test 1</option>
            <option value="">Test 2</option>
            <option value="">Test 3</option>
        </select>
</form>
```